# Android NDK app (native lib .so) loads on the hardware but it can't be found on the emulator

Tags: android-ndk, android-emulator, tensorflow-lite

I am building tensorflow-lite for android API24 using the documented method in android studio. The build files such as CMakeLists.txt and build.gradle are all unaltered.

The System.loadlibrary('libnative-lib.so') call for the tflow-lite java application works on the phone hardware, but when I try to run it on the emulator, I get the error:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.whisper.android.tflitecpp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.whisper.android.tflitecpp-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libnative-lib.so"`

I checked the .so files, and the time stamps indicate the `libnative-lib.so` is getting built for the emulator, just as it does for the hardware.

I also tried building the android demo app 'hello world' at the same API24 level, and it runs on both the phone and the emulator.

I grepped the logcat for 'libnative' but it didn't give me any further info than the error above. Is there any guidance how better to search the logcat?

I'm at a loss to understand how the tensorflow-lite build cannot find the libnative-lib.so file on the emulator, any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: My first guess would be that you haven't built and/or packaged an x86 version of libnative-lib.so.  Have you looked at the contents of the APK?

Comment: I haven't built the x86 target, my phone is arm64_v8a. I did quickly try the 'x86_64' abiFilter, but it failed to build with undefined reference at linking and I didn't pursue it since I didn't think I needed it. In the apk however, I think you may have the problem. I hadn't checked it. But when I 'Run' in Android Studio on the phone, I can see libraries are placed in the .apk. When i 'Build Project' for emulator, the libraries are placed in the .apk. When i 'Run' for the emulator, the libraries AREN'T placed in the .apk. So something's amiss there that I can dig into, thanks!